# How to set unique theme for individual activities?

Tags: java, android

I declare a theme in res/values/themes.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
           parent="@style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Then I apply the theme in one of my activities by adding this line in the manifest:

```
android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme"
```

Then I get an error in themes.xml, saying: "error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@style/
 Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar'."

Additional info from the manifest:

```
android:minSdkVersion="13"
android:targetSdkVersion="18"
```

And I did clean the project.
What might be the probleme?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be:

```
parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar"
```

and *not*:

```
parent="@style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar"
```